# Testing Conditional Logic based on a Date

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, functional-testing

I have an C# MVC EF6 Code First solution. There is a project for repository, services, model and web. A requirement is a screen that lists out all the cases in the system. Case has a bool property called Attention that is read only that has some business logic in it that will return true if the ResponseDue property is > DateTime.Now.

For testing purposes, the client wants to be able to fake what date Today actually is so if the ResponseDue property is 3 weeks into the future they would be able to say what would this screen look like 3 weeks from now and make sure the cases listed get marked for attention when that date comes.

I am not sure how to accommodate this testing requirement without hurting design or performance. I was thinking of having a CompareDate property on the Case class that would default to DateTime.Now but could be set to a different date if needed but then I wasn't sure how to pass that date in from the service layer and then to the repository layer to then get all Cases but set the CompareDate to what got passed into the public virtual IEnumerable GetAll() method.

Comment: Take a look at the mocking frameworks like Microsoft Fakes or Moq. You may be able to plug these into your unit tests to simulate your data repositories returning future dates.

Answer (score 0):

What about defining a virtual method or property that you can override in the test.

Here is an example of this. Not the same property, but still a demonstration of the general concept.
http://unit-testing.net/CurrentArticle/How-To-Remove-Data-Dependencies-In-Unit-Tests.html

Alternatively you can use a mocking framework.

Comment: Yeah, the issue is however that I need the end user to do User Acceptance Testing not just unit testing so I wanted to provide an Easter Egg that would show up given a config setting that would allow the end user to "Set" the system date equal to a date in the future.